# Make specific function an instance of Monad in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, monads

I'm following Philip Wadler's paper on Monads ([The essence of functional programming)](http://www.eliza.ch/doc/wadler92essence_of_FP.pdf) but instead of using functions such as `unitM` or `bindM`, I'm trying to make the Monad `M` an instance of the Haskell `Monad`. I did this for the first and second variation. But now I'm trying to do this for the third variation where we have to create a Monad which also keeps the position of an error message.

The paper describes the following functions: (`E` is the error Monad from the second variation)

```
type Position = Integer

type P a = Position -> E a

unitP a = \p -> unitE a
errorP s = \p -> errorE (showpos p ++ ": " ++ s)
m `bindP` k = \p -> m p `bindE` (\x -> k x p)

showP m = showE (m 0)

resetP  :: Position -> P x -> P x
resetP q m = \p -> m q
```

Now, my question is: "How can I make `P a = Position -> E a` an instance of `Monad`?"

Comment: You need to wrap that in a `data` or (better) `newtype`. E.g. `newtype P a = P { unP :: Position -> E a }`. Prepare to add wrapping/unwrapping `P`/`unP` here and there, as needed, to your `unitP, bindP` functions.

Comment: Like [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.1.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#line-137).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom monad implementation:

```
    -- Otherwise you can't do the Applicative instance.
    import Control.Applicative


    -- Simple function
    foo :: String -> String
    foo x = do
        x ++ "!!!"

    -- Helper for printing Monads
    print2 :: (Show a) => MyBox a -> IO()
    print2 (MyBox x) = print x


    -- Custom type declaration
    data MyBox a = MyBox a


    -- MyBox functor
    instance Functor MyBox where  
        fmap f (MyBox x) = MyBox (f x)


    -- MyBox Applicative 
    instance Applicative MyBox where  
        pure = MyBox 
        (MyBox f) <*> x = f <$> x


    -- MyBox Monad
    instance Monad MyBox where  
        return x = MyBox x
        MyBox x >>= f  = f x 

    -- (MyBox as a functor) Use a function with a wrapped value
    result1 = foo <$> (MyBox "Brian")

    -- (MyBox as an Applicative) Use a wrapped function with a wrapped value
    result2 = (MyBox foo) <*> (MyBox "Erich")

    -- (MyBox as a Monad)  Use a wrapped value with a lambda (it can be chainable)
    myLambda1 = (\ x -> MyBox (x ++  " aaa"))
    myLambda2 = (\ x -> MyBox (x ++  " bbb"))
    myLambda3 = (\ x -> MyBox (x ++  " ccc"))
    result3 = (MyBox "Rick") 
        >>= myLambda1
        >>= myLambda2
        >>= myLambda3


    -- Another Monad syntax
    result4 = do
        x <- MyBox "A" 
        y <- MyBox "B"  
        z <- MyBox "C"  
        MyBox (x ++ y ++ z)


    main = do
        print2(result1) -- "Brian!!!"
        print2(result2) -- "Erich!!!"
        print2(result3) -- "Rick aaa bbb ccc"
        print2(result4) -- "ABC"
```